# Check if domain is available fails

Tags: php, dns

I have been using [this metode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15195813/2807030).

I have set it up on my site, but for some reason, it doesn't seems to work for all extensions.
As I set I did setup that code on my site, but modified it to check the requested domain name.

You can try it on my site [here](http://webman.io/checkdnsrr/).

So here you can see some working examples:
try: just.com, just.net, example.com and test.com.

Some not working examples:
try: just.dk, example.dk and test.dk

Here is the complete code I have on the site:

```
    <?php
    function checkDomainAvailability($domain_name){

    $server = 'whois.crsnic.net';
    // Open a socket connection to the whois server
    $connection = fsockopen($server, 43);
    if (!$connection) return false;
    // Send the requested doman name
    fputs($connection, $domain_name."\r\n");
    // Read and store the server response
    $response_text = ' :';
    while(!feof($connection)) {
        $response_text .= fgets($connection,128);
    }

    // Close the connection
    fclose($connection);

    // Check the response stream whether the domain is available
    if (strpos($response_text, 'No match for')) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    $domainname = 'accurst.com';
    if (isset($_GET['domain']))
        $domainname = $_GET['domain'];

    if(checkDomainAvailability($domainname)) echo 'Domain : '.$domainname.' is Available';
    else echo 'Domain : '.$domainname.' is Already Taken';

?>
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Probably because the whois server doesn't support those top level domains : The Registry database contains ONLY .COM, .NET, .EDU domains and
Registrars.

Comment: Seems like you are right, it works only for the Top Level Domains, but how will I then check the order domains extensions? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because the whois server doesn't support those top level domains. Take a look at [whomsy](http://whomsy.com/apidoc)

Comment: Thanks, but whenever I try out [whomsy](http://whomsy.com/apidoc), I just get the follwoing response: `{"domain":"test.org","type":"success","message":"WHOIS LIMIT EXCEEDED - SEE WWW.PIR.ORG\/WHOIS FOR DETAILS"}`

Comment: Yeah that's the problem with whois queries. You'd have to pay for the better api's

Comment: Where can I buy access to those API's? Cause maybe it is worth it.